# Monotonicity of matrix inverse of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If $A$ and $B$ are positive definite, $A-B$ is positive definite, can we say $B^{-1}-A^{-1}$ is positive definite? I think this should be true but I don't know how to prove it.

It would be great if someone can offer help :) Thanks a lot!.

Comment: If $A = I$ and $B = 2I$ then $B^{-1}-A^{-1} = -\dfrac{1}{2}I$, which is negative definite. Did you mean to include the condition that $A-B$ is positive definite?

Comment: You are right! Sorry I forgot to add it. I will edit the question now.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you so much! Somehow I didn't find this question before!